# Getting pem file uploaded in Azure Key Vault Keys

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have uploaded  a `pem` file to `Azure Key Vault Keys` via  azure portal and tried below  function to get the data using `"azure-keyvault": "^3.0.0-preview",`

```
client.getKey(vaultUri, keyName, keyVersion,  {maxresults : 10}, function(err, result)  {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(result,'-----------key-');   
})
```

#### result

```
{ key:
    { 
     kid: 'https://test.vault.azure.net/keys/test/1123123123lksldkf',
     kty: 'RSA',
     keyOps: [ 'sign', 'verify', 'wrapKey', 'unwrapKey', 'encrypt', 'decrypt' ],
     n: <Buffer  ... >,
     e: <Buffer > 
    },
    attributes: { enabled: true,
     created: 2016-02-09T08:48:27.000Z,
     updated: 2016-02-09T08:48:27.000Z,
     recoveryLevel: 'Purgeable'
    } 
}
```

How can i download the `pem` file from the `result` ,  any help is much appreciated. I'm pretty much new to azure vault  and trying out few things with `keys, secrets and certificates`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot download **key** in form of a cert file (whether is .pem or .pfx) from Azure Key Vault once the cert is uploaded to **Keys** store. Keys in Azure Key Vault is used purposely for signing/encrypting/decrypting operation. The return JSON is a format of JWT (Json Web Token) which only contains public part of your stored key. This basically means converting the output to form of PEM or X.509 is not possible.

Using **Keys**, you can back up your key but the backup is also protected inside Azure Key Vault which you have no way to retrieve or request to get the key body content. The backup is helpful in case you lose the key and want to recover it.

**(*might not in scope of the question but I'd love to introduce*)**

If you upload your certificate into Certificates store, you can only export CER contents of x509 certificate and generate a .cer file. You cannot export the entirely key including private key.

If you upload your certificate (saying a .pfx file) to Azure Key Vault in form of a secret, you can download it to your client programatically using a few of the ways below:

- Use `GetSecretAsyn()`
- Call KeyVault REST API

Both of the ways require secret identifier and access token (which Azure Active Directory gives you). You will then need to convert the return value from Base64 to the byte and write it into your client in form of **.pfx** file.

Below is the sample code that I used HttpClient in asynchornous mode to generate my uploaded PFX file (from Secrets store)

```
    public static async Task<string> GetSecret(HttpClient client)
    {
        string url = $"/secrets/cert01?api-version=2016-10-01";

        using (var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responsContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject jsonKv = JObject.Parse(responsContent);
            string secretBody = jsonKv["value"].ToString();
            return secretBody;
        }
    }

    public static async Task ExportPfx()
    {
        string filePath = @"test02.pfx";

        var key = await GetSecret();
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key);
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
        }

    }
```

After the certificate is exported, go to import it to your local machine and verify if it has the same thumbprint and other specs.

Note: the exported certificate (as a secret) from Key Vault **has no password** even you set it when uploading to Secret store.

Comment: That helped a lot, my understanding itself was wrong.  So for my use case  i can only use `Azure Key Vault Secrets` and  need to be in `pfx` file. Is that right ?

Comment: What is your purpose of storing pfx file as a secret in Azure Key Vault? Once I get your need, I'd be happy to provide more details.

Comment: I need to keep 

 `private.pem` and `server.crt` to run node server in `https`,
 `jwt public.pem` used to verify and
  `private.pem` used to decrypt some info .

As of now all these are maintained as part of the code, so my intention is to  keep it in azure vault and  download it as part of the build  without impacting existing application  code

Comment: @tomalex why do you need to download the pem file in case if you only need to decrypt. Imagine with Keys, your private key used to decrypt in Azure Key Vaults so you just need to call to it via the method I introduced above or REST to encrypt your target stuff. If the constraint is to download the private key then only Secrets support. Otherwise you’d need to change your approach.

Comment: im using 3rd party `node module` which expects certificate and decrypt logic is well inside the  module.

Comment: Kind of using similar approach as seen here, https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml#security-and-signatures

Comment: Perhaps it is not supported in your case since the main purpose of Azure Key Vault is for both decryption and encryption. If you don't use Azure Key Vault for decryption/encryption/signing then don't use Key. Just go with Secret. After retrieving secret, you pass it to your node server. In this case, your .pem file is considered a secret which needs to be protected in Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Kind of doing similar approach as you specified. So in azure vault it doesn't support to upload a file and retrieve as such.

Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: If storing your certificate as either Keys and Certificates, your certificate is stored in a protected place aka HSM and you cannot retrive the whole certificate. The only Secret type allows you to retrieve the whole thing including private and public part of the certificate.

Comment: This is not correct; Azure automatically creates a matching "secret" when you upload a cert to store your private key if it contains an exportable key.

To download the public certificate, you can use:

az keyvault certificate show --vault-name <vault-name> --name <certificate-name>

To download the private key, you can use

az keyvault secret show --vault-name <vault-name> --name <certificate-name>